# how to update URL adress when loading new content with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, title

basically i use functions like:

```
function ver_pregunta(id){
        $("#router").fadeOut(100).load('./includes/router.php?que=ver_pregunta&id='+id).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    }
```

to load new content asynch. ok, but i'm allways using same URL, how Can i just update URL, TITLE and DESCRIPTION with JS/JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only set the name anchor in the url basically yourpage.com/#/someurl/
it's not possible to change the whole url without reloading the whole page.

To set the name anchor you need to do this:

```
location.hash='#/my/name/anchor/path';
```

If you want to use it like that (to point to your page with name anchor) you'll need to define some kind of check to load proper content with `ver_pregunta` function, basically take the location.hash e.g. if your url = `www.someurl.com/#myid` you can run:

```
if(location.hash!=""){
   ver_pregunta(location.hash.substring(1));
}
```

or better set a list of allowed ids:

```
var mypaths={"myid1":1,"myid2":1,"myid3":1}
```

and compare it with `location.hash`:

```
if(location.hash!="")
  var lh=location.hash.substring(1);
  if(mypaths[lh]==1)ver_pregunta(lh);
}
```

For title use:

```
$('title').text('new title');
```

For description:

```
$('meta[http-equiv="description"]').attr('content','new description');
```

If you want to do it for SEO reasons it won't work, Google bots don't use JS, they'll pick up only static HTML

Cheers

G.

Comment: it was for SEO reasons. So i have to do it first static and then add jquery options, right? thank you very much for your REALLY usefull answer :)

Comment: yes, you basically need to reload the page to make it SEO friendly (with custom url, title, description), cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "#newurl";
document.title = 'new title'; 
$('meta[name=description]').attr("content", "new description")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's native window function.

```
window.location.replace('http://www.google.com/')
```